# Meteor Android relase apk not working

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, meteor, heroku

I built a react-meteor android app, which I signed with Android Studio for a **release**. 
The app is loading with a splash screen and then stuck in den loading screen of my React Komposer ( I guess the subscription does not get ready ).
However running the app via:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://fuldacity.de
```

runs the app successful, as well as running from signed **debug** apk.

**I really do not now where to start to debug this problem.** I guess there is a possiblity to get some error logs out of Android Studio? I would be really glad on any inspiration on how to tackle this problem!

Furthermore I have the feeling it is connected to my setup. I have a domain hosted by domainfactory, where I also get my https certificate from. The domain is then redirected to Heroku, where my App is hosted. I furthermore redirect all http:// accesses to https:// via the Meteor package **force-ssl**.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short the error was on domainfactory where I have choosen the IP instead of the domainname as A configuration for the nameserver. 
Domainfactory does not allow a the correct settings for usage of heroku. Now I use the nameservers of Route 53 which could setup the right CNAME settings to heroku.

For the debugging I also learned that you can

```
meteor run android-device --server https://fuldacity
```

then go to your chrome browser (on your pc) open the developer tools and there you can find remote devices which gives you all the error outputs from the client side! 
This let me to the network error, which only appeared on the mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
meteor add-platform android
```

After

```
meteor install-sdk android
```

After

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://fuldacity.de
```

Comment: Well, this is what I initially did and as mention working. My problem is that the signed apk from `build meteor ../fuldacity-build --server https://fuldacity.de` is not running, all of the others are running just fine